# How to connect to an Openvpn Access Server in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, mac, openvpn

I'm working at a company that uses a lot of openvpn **connections** to different customers. Most of them are **Openvpn Access Server**.

100% of my coworkers use Mac or Windows but I would like to use Linux, but had the next problem. They use a vpn client called **Viscosity** That has an option to download aditional info from those openvpn servers. So they connect just using **username and password**.

But when I try to connect I'm forced to give a **certificate + username and password**.

I could ask for a .ovpn file, but is not the best solution because in this job the vpn changes everytime and I need to have the same functionality as they do.

Answer (score 0):

This was pretty easy to solve once i knew what to look.

What solved my problem was using the API of openvpn Access Server.
Using `curl` you can download the ovpn file with certs and everything.

`curl -u vpnuser:vpnpassword https://<vpn-ip>:<vpn-port>/rest/GetUserlogin`

If server has no valid ssl cert you can add the `-k` option (Not secure though)

I hope this answer helps anyone in a situation like mine a few month ago.